# Who is being supported and protected in Daniel 11:1?

Tags: referent-identification, prophecy, daniel, niv

Daniel 11:1 NIV

> 11 1 And in the first year of Darius the Mede, ***I took my stand to support and protect him***.)

In the above text its not clear who is being supported and protected.

Who is the referent in the above text?

Comment: Is it not clear that "him" is Darius?

Answer (score 2):

The chapter break here is most unfortunate. Chapters ten through twelve should be read as a complete, unbroken discourse. There is no break in the conversion between the end of chapter ten and the beginning if chapter twelve. 11:1 belongs as part of 10:21.
The antecedent of “him” is not Darius but Michael from 10:21. God moved Darius to return the Jews to their own land and it is clear from chapter ten that opposition to the will of God in this matter came from the demonic world via the “prince of the kingdom of Persia.” Gabriel alludes here to the fact the he had strengthened and assisted Michael in that other worldly struggle.